# Python module for HTTP: fill in forms, retrieve result

Tags: python, http, request

I'd like to use Python to access an HTTP website, fill out a form, submit the form, and retrieve the result.

What modules are suitable for the task?

Comment: What modules have you tried?

Comment: Mechanize can do it, but I'd just use Requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the simple [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and the more sophisticated [httplib2](https://code.google.com/p/httplib2/). Both are 100% suitable for this task.

Comment: If the website utilizes javascript, you could also add [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [python-spidermonkey](https://github.com/davisp/python-spidermonkey) to your enhance your existing codebase.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot advise you with detailed instructions since you never gave us details of your problem.
However, most probably you want to use urllib2 to fetch an HTML page:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://python.org/')
html = response.read()
```

You should then parse the form, find out all the data fields you need to send with their names , and then create your own POST or GET request, depending on the form type.

To send a POST request:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
      'location' : 'Northampton',
      'language' : 'Python' }

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

To send a GET request:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
data = {}
data['name'] = 'Somebody Here'
data['location'] = 'Northampton'
data['language'] = 'Python'
url_values = urllib.urlencode(data)
url = 'http://www.example.com/example.cgi'
full_url = url + '?' + url_values
data = urllib2.urlopen(full_url)
```